# Multipart Exception, Java, SpringMVC, springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Failed to parse multipart servlet request;

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, csv

Пишу импортер данных из csv файла в бд,
имею вот такой метод контроллёра

```
@PostMapping(value = "/createTable", consumes = MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity importCsvData(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) throws Exception {

    userService.parse(file.getInputStream());
    return ok().build();
```

И вот такой метод сервиса

```
@Override
public void parse(InputStream reader) {
    CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReader(new InputStreamReader(reader));
    String[] record;

    try {
        while ((record = csvReader.readNext()) != null){
            User user = new User();
            if (record[0].equals("ssoid"))
                continue;
            user.setSsoid(record[0]);
            user.setTs(Integer.parseInt(record[1]));
            user.setGrp(record[2]);
            user.setType(record[3]);
            user.setSubtype(record[4]);
            user.setUrl(record[5]);
            user.setOrgid(record[6]);
            user.setFormid(record[7]);
            user.setCode(record[8]);
            user.setLtpa(record[9]);
            user.setSudirresponse(record[10]);
            user.setYmdh(record[11]);
            userRepository.save(user);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>ImporterCSVtoDB</groupId>
<artifactId>ImporterCSV</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>8</source>
                <target>8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.11.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>42.2.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
        <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
        <version>4.6</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Код контроллёра.

```
    package ru.novikov.Controller;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
    import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;
    import ru.novikov.Service.UserService;

import static org.springframework.http.MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE;
    import static org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity.ok;

    @Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    public UserService userService;
@GetMapping("/createTable")
public String Test() {
    userService.createTable();
    return "createTable";
}


@PostMapping(value = "/createTable", consumes = MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity importCsvData(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) throws Exception {

    userService.parse(file.getInputStream());
    return ok().build();

}
```

При тесте данного пост запроса в Postman вылетает целый список ошибок

```
<h1>HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error</h1>
<hr class="line" />
<p><b>Type</b> Exception Report</p>
<p><b>Message</b> Request processing failed; nested exception is
    org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Failed to parse multipart servlet request; nested
    exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to process parts as no multi-part configuration has been
    provided</p>
<p><b>Description</b> The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.
</p>
<p><b>Exception</b></p>
<pre>org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Failed to parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to process parts as no multi-part configuration has been provided
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
```

**Root Cause**

```
org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Failed to parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to process parts as no multi-part configuration has been provided
    org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.handleParseFailure(StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.java:124)
    org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.parseRequest(StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.java:115)
    org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.<init>(StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.java:88)
    org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.<init>(StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.java:72)
    org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MultipartResolutionDelegate.resolveMultipartArgument(MultipartResolutionDelegate.java:103)
    org.springframework.web.method.annotation.RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver.resolveName(RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver.java:166)
    org.springframework.web.method.annotation.AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.java:108)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:121)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:167)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:134)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:888)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
```

**Root Cause**

```
<pre>java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to process parts as no multi-part configuration has been provided
org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParts(Request.java:2801)
org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getParts(Request.java:2769)
org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getParts(RequestFacade.java:1098)
org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.parseRequest(StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.java:95)
org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.&lt;init&gt;(StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.java:88)
org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.&lt;init&gt;(StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.java:72)
org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MultipartResolutionDelegate.resolveMultipartArgument(MultipartResolutionDelegate.java:103)
org.springframework.web.method.annotation.RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver.resolveName(RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver.java:166)
org.springframework.web.method.annotation.AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.java:108)
org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:121)
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:167)
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:134)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:888)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, всю голову сломал, не понимаю в чём проблема, спасибо!

Comment: Прикрепите, пожалуйста, pom.xml и полный код контроллера. У вас явно ошибки в конфигурации приложения.

Comment: Прикрепил код, почему то не вставляется красиво, извините)